# Multiple Groups Mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

What does a multiple groups query actually accomplish?  For example, if you have

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $id GROUP BY date, quantity, buyer;
```

What does that mean in plain English?  I know what it means to "Group by date", but is "group by date, quantity" like a 2-d array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means ALL of the GROUP BY elements have to be identical in order for the records to be grouped.

For example, using:

```
GROUP BY start_date, category_id
```

Would keep rows with the same start date but different category_id as separate returned elements.  Rows would need to have the same exact start_date and category_id in order to be grouped together.

Comment: So, is it analogous to `DISTINCT(CONCAT(col1, 'operator', col2))` (except that `DISTINCT` only takes one column)?